# System Info from Universal Windows Platform or .NET Standard 2.0 class Library

Tags: powershell, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

I am developing a UWP app with .NET Standard class library for Utility logic.
In this application I need to collect some metadata related to operating PC

I have come up with following structure to read the data

```
 public static void LoadSystemInfo(this Payload payload)
        {
            payload.SystemInfo = new SystemInfo
            {
                Machine = new Machine
                {
                    SerialNumber = SystemInfo("SerialNumber"),
                    UuId = SystemInfo("UuId"),
                },
                HostName = SystemInfo("HostName"),
                OsVersion = SystemInfo("OsVersion"),
                OsManufacturer = SystemInfo("OsManufacturer"),
                DeviceId = SystemInfo("DeviceId"),
                SystemManufacturer = SystemInfo("SystemManufacturer"),
                SystemModel = SystemInfo("SystemModel"),
                SystemType = SystemInfo("SystemType"),
                SystemLocale = SystemInfo("SystemLocale"),
                TimeZone = SystemInfo("TimeZone"),
                TotalPhysicalMemory = SystemInfo("TotalPhysicalMemory"),
                AvailablePhysicalMemory = SystemInfo("AvailablePhysicalMemory"),
            };
        }
        private static string  SystemInfo(string key)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "SerialNumber":
                    return GetMotherBoardId();
                case "UuId":
                    return "";
                case "HostName":
                    return "";
                case "OsVersion":
                    return "";
                case "OsManufacturer":
                    return "";
                case "DeviceId":
                    return "";
                case "SystemManufacturer":
                    return "";
                case "SystemModel":
                    return "";
                case "SystemType":
                    return "";
                case "SystemLocale":
                    return "";
                case "TimeZone":
                    return "";
                case "TotalPhysicalMemory":
                    break;
                case "AvailablePhysicalMemory":
                    return "";
                default:
                    return $"Missing Case for {key}";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I tried to get Get Mother Board Id as below

```
public static string GetMotherBoardId()
        {
            string mbInfo = string.Empty;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2");
            scope.Connect();
            ManagementObject wmiClass = new ManagementObject(scope,
                new ManagementPath("Win32_BaseBoard.Tag=\"Base Board\""), new ObjectGetOptions());

            foreach (PropertyData propData in wmiClass.Properties)
            {
                if (propData.Name == "SerialNumber")
                    mbInfo = $"{propData.Name,-25}{Convert.ToString(propData.Value)}";
            }

            return mbInfo;
        }
```

That throws error as **System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop applications.**

How do I get all the above properties from local PC which is running my UWP app.

Also tried powershell script like below

```
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        powerShellInstance.AddCommand("get-wmiobject");
                        powerShellInstance.AddParameter("class", "Win32_ComputerSystemProduct");
                        //powerShellInstance.AddScript(
                        //    "get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UUID");
                        Collection<PSObject> psOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

                    }
```

that gives error as below

> The term 'get-wmiobject' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

**Update**

---

Followed this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/retrieving-an-instance and it still fails

```
string Namespace = @"root\cimv2";
string className = "Win32_LogicalDisk";

CimInstance myDrive = new CimInstance(className, Namespace);
CimSession mySession = CimSession.Create("localhost");
CimInstance searchInstance = mySession.GetInstance(Namespace, myDrive);
```

Throws following error

> Access to a CIM resource was not available to the client.

When I try this

```
  ManagementObjectSearcher mgmtObjSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");
                    ManagementObjectCollection colDisks = mgmtObjSearcher.Get();
```

I get this error

> System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop
>   applications.

When I try this

```
string command = "Get-Command Write-Output";
                    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        var results = ps.AddScript(command).Invoke();
                        foreach (var result in results)
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
                        }
                        ps.Commands.Clear();
                    }
```

I get this error

> An error occurred while creating the pipeline. --> Method not found:
>   'System.Text.StringBuilder
>   System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(System.Text.StringBuilder)'.

Any help i greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled your switch based on data from microsoft toolkit [`SystemInformation`](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/e383eeadb4bdcf07dcca4e2768f806eb2ef732f7/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp/Helpers/SystemInformation.cs) helper, hostname from [`NetworkInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation#Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkInformation_GetHostNames) class, timezone from [`TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezone.currenttimezone?view=netframework-4.7.2) and SystemLocale from [`HomeGeographicRegion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences#examples)

I haven't filled TotalPhysicalMemory because in UWP you can not get the system RAM information since it is sandbox. But you can get app memory usage limit from [`MemoryManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.MemoryManager#properties)

For `SerialNumber` you can use `SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher()` will receive raw data as buffer you can process it.

```
private static string SystemInfo(string key)
{
   EasClientDeviceInformation deviceInfo = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
   switch (key)
   {
     case "SerialNumber":
        break ;
     case "UuId":
        return deviceInfo.Id.ToString();
     case "HostName":
        var hostNames = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
        return  hostNames.FirstOrDefault(name => name.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)?.DisplayName ?? "???";                     
     case "OsVersion":
        ulong version = ulong.Parse(AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamilyVersion);
        return  ((version & 0xFFFF000000000000L) >> 48).ToString()+"."+
          ((version & 0x0000FFFF00000000L) >> 32).ToString()+"."+((version & 0x00000000FFFF0000L) >> 16).ToString()+"."+(version & 0x000000000000FFFFL).ToString();
     case "OsManufacturer":
        return deviceInfo.OperatingSystem;
     case "DeviceId":
        return "";
     case "SystemManufacturer":
        return deviceInfo.SystemManufacturer; 
     case "SystemModel":
        return deviceInfo.SystemProductName;
     case "SystemType":
        return Package.Current.Id.Architecture.ToString();
     case "SystemLocale":
        return Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.HomeGeographicRegion;
     case "TimeZone":
        return TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName.ToString();
     case "TotalPhysicalMemory":
        break;
     case "AvailablePhysicalMemory":
        return ((float)MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit / 1024 / 1024).ToString();
     default:
        return $"Missing Case for {key}";
    }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vignesh, still struggling to get SerialNumber and ProductId.
Serial Number through Powershell script get-ciminstance win32_bios | format-list serialnumber and ProductID from command prompt by typing systeminfo.

Comment: UWP has some system level api's restricted. If you really need to access those you can create a [appservice][1] to run a small wpf snippet and get data to UWP app. [1] : https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample